# Error Wordpress Multisite "Unknown login key"

Tags: wordpress

After starting session, I will start my website and automatically redirects me to:

action=login&dm=d38d5f257c6992938b254ee8ec8b7cd6&k=e9a011cf0f3c7fbacf2adeeee9415a0c&t=552877987

with message "Unknown login key"

Not as debug or fix.

Also, when I create new post appears not published and 404

Who pued guide or help me please?